# How to control cursor/caret size with CSS

Tags: html, css

I'm trying to control the caret size in a html textarea. The size seems to default to the line height, is there a way to manually control it?

Comment: You can set the line-height via css.

Comment: Yep I thanks @LeRoy, unfortunately I need to keep the line-height as is. It's fairly large so the caret looks unusually big compared to the font-size.

Comment: Look at this may be got some ideas: https://stackoverflow.com/a/3758063/1830909

Answer (score 11, accepted):

There isn't any way to change how the caret looks in a textarea. If you want to do that, you'll have to use something other than a textarea, such as a div or a canvas element and control everything with JavaScript.

Comment: actually theres a way to change the caret's color with caret-color or caretColor in css and js

Answer (score 3):

Worth noting that some fonts the default size and position of the cursor just looks weird. If this is a high priority for you, it might be worth at least considering switching to a different font. Here is an example of one Google font that looks super weird and two that don't:

[image: example of Cutive Google Font with odd caret positioning]

[image: example of Abel Google Font caret]

[image: example of Roboto Condensed Google Font caret]

You might also have luck generating your webfont files with different settings. The [font squirrel webfont generator](https://www.fontsquirrel.com/tools/webfont-generator) in Expert Mode has settings for **vertical metrics** and **x-height matching** that may help with this issue. Most paid webfonts from different foundries also have similar export settings now.  Definitely a time consuming task to tweak settings, export repeatedly, install the new files and check your work, but can often be worth it.