# How to increase cursor caret thickness in HTML?

Tags: html, css, browser, progressive-web-apps

Native apps on Android have a better cursor caret width. But for web apps and pwa, the caret width seem to be very thin. Could someone tell me how can I increase the cursor width, if it is even feasible?

Comment: You will need to use an image as the cursor. Be aware browser support is mostly good, but there are a few catches. See this answer for an example. https://stackoverflow.com/questions/18551277/using-external-images-for-css-custom-cursors

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can't change the way the cursor caret looks in a textarea. The most you can do is change the color. https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/caret-color.

I suggest you take a look at these links too:

[How to control cursor/caret size with CSS](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6090893/how-to-control-cursor-caret-size-with-css)

[How to adjust the Caret (blinking cursor) size inside searchbar with css](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/15249288/how-to-adjust-the-caret-blinking-cursor-size-inside-searchbar-with-css)

I hope I helped somewhat.