# Change HTML text input cursor symbol to "block"

Tags: javascript, html, css, input, text-cursor

> **Possible Duplicate:**
> [How to use this square cursor in a HTML input field?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3758023/how-to-use-this-square-cursor-in-a-html-input-field)

Is there a way to change the cursor style of an HTML text `<input>`'s cursor to the "block" kind like a command prompt?

[image: Block cursor]

If not, is there a way to hide the default text cursor then append a block character at the end of the text that cannot be deleted?

Thanks.

Comment: What browser compat are you looking at?

Answer (score -3):

To hide the cursor you can use : cursor: none;

Comment: I think the OP meant *caret*, not cursor.