# How to set the position of a custom cursor to follow an input box?

Tags: javascript, inform7

I'm looking for an effective way to customize the text cursor (caret) in my inform game when viewed a website (generated through [Parchment](https://github.com/curiousdannii/parchment)).

I'm working off of [this example](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3758023/how-to-use-this-square-cursor-in-a-html-input-field), but my knowledge of Javascript is shaky and I'm uncertain how to force the custom text cursor I've created to position itself to the one it's replacing.

[I have a demo here](http://bertytours.com/if/play.html) with the original input field still displayed. The custom cursor is sitting in the top-left corner and blinks when selected. How can I accomplish this?

Comment: Like this? https://jsfiddle.net/whwv3cb4/

Answer (score 1):

So the best idea from my perspective is to hide the input (this is what a lot of apps do like google docs, atom, vscode, etc) and then create a fake cursor and "input" box. The code for it would be something like:

```
var input = document.getElementById('input');
var output = document.getElementById('output');

input.addEventListener('keyup', function() {
  output.removeChild(document.getElementById('cursor'));
  output.innerHTML += input.value;
  input.value = '';
  makeCursor();
});

document.addEventListener('click', function() {
  input.focus();
});

function makeCursor() {
  var cursor = document.createElement('div');
  cursor.setAttribute('id', 'cursor');
  output.appendChild(cursor);
}
makeCursor();
```

and I have a runnable example here: https://jsfiddle.net/whwv3cb4/2/

Comment: This looks great, thank you. :)  I'm having trouble targeting the input's class instead of its Id. Why can't I use getElementsByClassname? I updated the Fiddle.

Parchment generates it's own code on load and assigns a unique Id to the input whenever the line moves, so I have to target it by the class LineInput instead.

Comment: Updating the fiddle makes a new link, so you've have to send it to me :)
As well getElements has an S so it's probably returning more than 1 element. Try getElementsByClassname("")[0]